# python typing module missing the Coroutine class in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, type-hinting, typing

I am trying to write code which uses the `Coroutine` class, as described in the [typing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine).

It's look like it's available in `python 3.5`, but when I am typing to import it throws me an `ImportError`:

```
In [1]: from typing import Coroutine
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Coroutine'

Then, I tried to run the code in Python 3.6 and it worked fine.
Does this class not available in `python 3.5`? If not, why it's appear in the documentation (of python 3.5 in particular)? I tried to run it with `python 3.5.2`.

Comment: I tried importing in python 3.5 and its working correctly. Try checking your version of python again

Comment: @RajSubit What version of python do you use?

Comment: Just tried in python 3.5.3

Comment: Fixed my question to specific `python 3.5.2`.

Comment: @YuvalPruss The documentation you refer to is for version 3.5.3. RajSubit seemed to have verified that everything works as expected for 3.5.3. If you check the [documentation for 3.5.2](https://docs.python.org/release/3.5.2/library/typing.html) you'll see that `Coroutine` is _not_ mentioned there. Hence the version of your Python distribution and the documentation you referred to just don't match.

Comment: This is a known problem -- since the `typing` module is a part of the standard library since 3.5.0, you can't have access to any of the changes to `typing` that were made since then. There were plans to add a `typing_extensions` module to pypi which would contain these missing definitions (including Coroutine) which would be special-cased by typecheckers, but the [discussion seems to have fizzled out](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/435). Maybe you can post something there to try and revive the discussion?

Answer (score 10):

The library `typing` was not official on 3.5, but became official on 3.6. So for older than 3.6 you need to install a specific library : [Typing module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing) 
For 3.6 you need nothing because it became official

Comment: But the entire module is available in `python 3.5`, it's just this specific class  is not available, although it's written in the documentation.

Comment: Did you at least try to install this module ? Maybe on 3.5.2 every was port except the coroutine. It's maybe a reason why he became official only on 3.6. If after making a pip of this module it's still doesn't work, then I am wrong.

Comment: @LudovicGuerra I checked with Python 3.5.2: `pip install typing` `=>` `Successfully installed typing-3.6.1`. However `Coroutine` is still missing in the `typing` module. Admittedly the docs are for 3.5.3.

Comment: in 3.5, running `pip install typing` won't help as the stdlib `typing` module will still shadow the site-packages `typing` module

Comment: @AnthonySottile You are right, the `typing` module from pip actually contains the `Coroutine` class.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this issue with `Awaitable` (which suffers from the same problem as `Coroutine`). It's missing from the stdlib and there seems to be no easy way to just pull it from pypi. If you're tied into Python 3.5, then this workaround may work for you:

We rely on the fact that despite the Python 3.5 stdlib `typing` does not contain `Coroutine` (or `Awaitable`), `mypy` doesn't actually appear to use the stdlib `typing`. Instead, when invoked it uses its own version of the `typing` module. So, as long as your `mypy` is up to date, it will know about `typing.Coroutine` (and `typing.Awaitable`). So the only thing you need to do is fake the existence of these types for runtime (where you can't import them). This can be achieved like so:

```
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING
try:
    from typing import Coroutine
except ImportError:
    class _Coroutine:
        # Fake, so you can do Coroutine[foo, bar, baz]
        # You could assert the proper number of items are in the slice,
        # but that seems like overkill, given that mypy will check this
        # and at runtime you probably no longer care
        def __getitem__(self, index: Any) -> None:
            pass

    if not TYPE_CHECKING:
        Coroutine = _Coroutine()
```

After this, use `Coroutine[A, B, C]` as normal. Your code will typecheck properly and at runtime you won't have any issues due to it being missing from the 3.5 stdlib.

This does prevent you from doing any RTTI, but AFAIK that's part of a PEP that landed experimentally in 3.6 (or maybe 3.7) anyways.

For `Awaitable`, it's the same workaround, except `s/Coroutine/Awaitable`.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same issue and after wasting an hour, found this solution [here](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/156#).

```
import typing
try:
    from pyppeteer import launch
except ImportError:
    from typing_extensions import Coroutine
    typing.Coroutine = Coroutine
    from pyppeteer  import launch
    from typing import Any, Callable, Coroutine, Dict, List, Optional
```

I hope it helps anyone else as well.